# How to remove the sort when it was set from the column tab

Tags: sorting, google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts, reverse, history

I clicked the 'sort sheet a --> z' on the drop down from the little tab at the top of the column, now I cannot revert my sheet back to its pre-sorted state. And connected sheets are now showing incorrect information.

1st, is there a way to remove this 'sort' and go back to the previous way, where everything was listed in order of input?

2nd, is there a way to make sure the row numbers stay with the same row data on sort, as per a regular database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`Z`**</kbd> to go back.

if it's not possible then press <kbd>**`CTRL`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`LEFT ALT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`SHIFT`**</kbd> + <kbd>**`H`**</kbd> and revert your changes there

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks that got me back to where I needed to be. How does one sort without losing data integrity between different sheets? How to lock the row numbers to the data?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, it's proprietary :o Do you think I need a separate numbered column, distinct from the number column provided? but that's not exactly going to work is it, when the sheet is referenced by: sheetname!A46  - yet 46 could become 1 depending on how one sorts it. Hmmm...

Comment: well, it's hard to tell when there is nothing to see/test. if I understand it then you are trying to sort some column but you want not to lose order between sorted column and rest of your dataset. if that so then you should try to crate Filtered View which will allow you to sort column with linked row references. https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkdQM.png